# Hashref/Arrayref, don't understand the following behavior

Tags: perl

I have an arrayref with hashrefs, the structure looks like the following:

```
[
{
"id"   => 1,
"name" => "name1"
},
{
"id"   => 2,
"name" => "name2"
}
]
```

when i want to push a hash (no hashref) into this array, the structure looks odd.

```
my %hash = (id => 3, name => "name3");
push(@$array, %hash);
```

the structure would look like:

```
[
{
"id"   => 1,
"name" => "name1"
},
{
"id"   => 2,
"name" => "name2"
}
"id"   => 3,
"name" => "name3"
]
```

so the key value pairs are pushed in the array as single values, not as a hash?
when i push with `\%hash`, it works.

```
push(@$array, \%hash);
```

but i really don't understand why i get a different object structure, as `ref` just means it's a pointer to a storage location?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you need to know is there's no such thing as multi-dimensional data structures in perl. And this is largely true of *all* languages, they just abstract the problem in different ways.

You get an array (or hash) of references, to sub arrays (or hashes).

So if you try to push a hash into an array, it's first evaluated in a list context - the pairs of key/values are spat out in a random order, and then inserted as array elements into the array.

If you want to have a hash as a subelement of an array, you *must* do it by reference - although there's a few mechanisms by which you can do this subtly.

e.g.:

```
push ( @$array, {%hash} );
```

The hash evaluation will be a list of key-value pairs in a list, but then the `{}` act as a constructor for an anonymous hash - that's then inserted into the array.

It's still doing the same thing as in your example the array contains a hash-ref element, it's just an anonymous one that copies your `%hash` instead of referring to the original.

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $array = []; 

my %hash = (id => 3, name => "name3");
push @$array, \%hash; 


#note how these are the same ref number
print $array->[0],"\n";
print \%hash;
print Dumper $array;
print "\n";

#empty array;
$array = []; 

push(@$array, {%hash});

#note different number. 
print \%hash,"\n";
print $array->[0],"\n";


print Dumper $array;
```